# create an UTF-8 string with BOM

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I'm using MD5 function and Base64 Encoding to generate a User Secret (used to login to data layer of the used API)

I did the code in [javascript](http://www.adwiza.com/t/calculate.htm) and it's fine, but in Objective C I'm strugling with the BOM

my code is:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] 
                 initWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%d", 
                    [auth uppercaseString], 
                    [user uppercaseString], 
                    [pwd uppercaseString], 
                    totalDaysSince2000];

NSString *sourceString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02x%02x%02x%@", 
                          0xEF, 
                          0xBB, 
                          0xBF, 
                          str]; 

NSString *strMd5 = [sourceString MD5]; 

NSData *sourceData = [strMd5 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  
NSString *base64EncodedString = [[sourceData base64EncodedString] autorelease];
```

using the code above I'm getting into the memory:

[image]
<sub>(source: [balexandre.com](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-06_1523.png))</sub>

witch is not what I really need...

I even tried with

```
"%c%c%c%@", (char)239, (char)187, (char)191, str
```

with no luck...

using `UTF8String` does not seam to append the BOM automatically as in C# :-(

How can I append the BOM correctly ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try embedding the BOM directly in the format string as escaped character literals:

```
NSString *sourceString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"\357\273\277%@", str];
```

Answer (score 8):

You might have to add the BOM to the NSData object, not the NSString. Something like this:

```
char BOM[] = {0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF};
NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData data];
[data appendBytes:BOM length:3];
[data appendData:[strMd5 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue with Swift and opening CSV fime in Excel.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879198/adding-utf-8-bom-to-string-blob) also helped me a lot.

Simple solution for swift with CSV file:

```
let BOM = "\u{FEFF}"
csvFile.append(BOM)
```