# iOS write to CSV file: which encoding to use

Tags: ios, csv, character-encoding, utf-16

In my iOS app, I have a feature that writes data to a CSV file. This works fine in most cases with the following:

```
[csvString writeToFile: filePath atomically:YES encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

I recently got an email from a Japanese user that the CSV file exported has weird symbols instead of Japanese characters. So I switched to using NSUTF16StringEncoding and it seems to work fine for Japanese characters as well.

So the question is: is it better to use NSUTF16StringEncoding, or are there any drawbacks to doing this? It seems that other examples I've seen for writing to CSV files (including [CHCSVParser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser)) use
NSUTF8StringEncoding, so I'm not sure which one to prefer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no a "better" encoding.

UTF-8 uses a variable number of bytes per each character, from 1 to 4. UTF-16 uses always 2 bytes for every character. What is best, is really up to you and your business. In theory, if your users are mostly based in Asia and use primarily non-ASCII character, files encoded in UTF-16 are smaller. If your users are primarily living in the Western world and use Latin-based alphabets, using UTF-8 makes every file 50% smaller.

I believe your problem is not with the choice of the encoding, but rather with the presentation. Text editors cannot guess the encoding of a file, so it's possible that your Japanese user was using a text editor that defaults to UTF-16, and thus was unable to represent UTF-8 character sequences correctly. 
The solution to this problem is to using the BOM sequence, as per this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2585194/192024 (in short: just add those 3 bytes at the beginning of the file to tell editors what encoding to use)