# any qr code generator library with unicode support?

Tags: php, python, qr-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unicode Encoding and decoding issues in QRCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612062/unicode-encoding-and-decoding-issues-in-qrcode)

I need to generate qr code offline , 
but I need a library which supports unicode ( arabic language for example ) ...
It doesn't matter which language is it written in , but I prefer python and php.

can anyone suggest any?
thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612062/unicode-encoding-and-decoding-issues-in-qrcode

Answer (score 1):

[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing) has a Java-based encoder which will let you specify the character encoding you want to use to encode the text as bytes in the QR code. Be aware though that anything except ISO-8859-1 is not necessarily going to work, as this is the only encoding allowed in the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net ?